# What are .dbg files and what they have to do with `-g` option in gcc

Tags: c, debugging, compilation, makefile

I'm writing a simple program for my university classes and there is a requirement that we should attach Makefile to the project and "generate `.dbg` file if `make debug` is called in which there will be debugging symbols contained (option `-g` of compiling)"

I don't understand anything from this description, I also cannot find any information about `.dbg` files online. What are they and how to generate one? Compiling my source code with `-g` flag doesn't appear to generate such file...

Comment: It seems your instructor wants to generate `output` with `make` and `output.dbg` (which is compiled with -g) with `make debug`.

Comment: So they should both be just executables?

Comment: well i cannot guess for sure. In my experience, teaching assistants usually aren't capable of writing well-defined assignments, so the best bet would be to ask your TA.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a micro-controller course?
In order to debug your executables, the executable should be built in debug mode. That means, the debugging information like symbol names are embedded in the executable. This implies, the executable is bigger in size. 
Usually no problem on a PC, but on a uC with limited resources such an executable may not be flashed.

Most compilers including GCC allows to store debugging information in a separate file ([e.g. see this link](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html)), so the executable itself remains small and the debugger loads the symbols from another file (eg. `your_exe.dbg`)